# OMNET++ interface to other Eclipse instance

Tags: omnet++

I have an Javs application running in a Eclipse instance, and want to stimulate the simulation running in the OMNET++ Eclipse environment.
Is it possible to send events between the two Eclipse Instances?

Simple Example: Using the Tic-toc tutorial example, can i put the TOC module in another eclipse instance?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple misunderstandings here that should be addressed first:
- Eclipse is the JUST the development environment for OMNeT++, simulations are running in their OWN process totally unrelated to Eclipse. In fact you can devlop and use OMNeT++ simulations without ever touching or starting the IDE using just any 3rd party editor.
- As stated, simulations are running in their own process with a graphical or command line runtime (Cmdenv, Tkenv or recently Qtenv). Now what you may be interested is: can you run a simulation that is running in TWO independent processes? The answer is yes. It is called parallel simulation (look up in the OMNeT++ manual how to do it). There are some examples also in the samples/cqn/parsim folder. (a simulation running in 3 separate partition)

Note that you may need to install MPI to use this effectively.